# Android tgkill Native Crash

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

I'm seeing this native crash with the following stack trace.

This happens in Android 7.0 & 7.1 only. Nothing new has been added to the app, which has been in production for a few years, but with more devices being updated to Nougat this crash happens frequently now.

Any advise would be appreciated.

```
backtrace:
  native: pc 000000000004a230  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
  native: pc 00000000000479c3  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
  native: pc 000000000001d9c5  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
  native: pc 0000000000019511  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
  native: pc 0000000000017150  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
  native: pc 000000000031b5ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+252)
  native: pc 00000000000b4d4b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+866)
  native: pc 000000000023a259  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1584)
  native: pc 000000000023a523  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+66)
  native: pc 0000000000272313  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI14SetObjectFieldEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP9_jfieldIDS4_+558)
  native: pc 000000000006450b  /data/app/com.a.s-2/base.apk
  native: pc 0000000000ab9f51  /data/app/com.a.s-2/oat/arm/base.odex
```

Here's a list of devices that are effected:

```
Galaxy S7 Edge (hero2qltetmo)
Galaxy J7 Prime (on7xelte)
Galaxy S8+ (dream2lte)
Galaxy Note5 (nobleltetmo)
Galaxy J5(2016) (j5xnlte)
Mate 9 (HWMHA)  
Galaxy S6 Edge+ (zenlte)
LG X Style (k6b)    
Galaxy S7 Edge (hero2lte)   
Galaxy Note5 (noblelte) 
Galaxy S7 (heroqlteatt) 
Galaxy S7 (herolte)
Galaxy S8+ (dream2qltesq)
Galaxy S8+ (dream2lteks)
Moto G(4) Plus (athene_f)
Galaxy A7(2016) (a7xelte)
Y6 2017 (HWMYA-L6737)
```

How ti fix this crash... Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you ever figure out any additional information?